# Escape space and resolve variable in Jenkins powershell script not working

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I tried different ways to escape the space in "Program Files" but this is not working. I receive the following error in Jenkins after this part is executed:

> powershell.exe : FileStream was asked to open a device that was not a file. For support for devices like 'com1:' or 'lpt1:', call  At
>   C:\web\JenkinsMaster\workspace\XXX@tmp\durable-d3011838\powershellWrapper.ps1:5
>   char:3
>   +   & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Fi ...
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (FileStream was ... 'lpt1:', call :String) [], RemoteException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   CreateFile, then use the FileStream constructors that take an OS handle as an IntPtr.
>
> - CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], NotSupportedException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
> - PSComputerName        : XXXXX

```
powershell script: '''
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "XXXX" -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "XXXX",$pass
$sessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName XXXXXXXX -UseSSL -Credential $cred -SessionOption $sessionOption
Copy-Item $env:WORKSPACE\\* -Destination "C:\\data\\install\\" -Filter *TEST* -Recurse -Force -Verbose -ToSession $session
$filename = $env:JOB_NAME + "_" + $env:BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME + "_wwwroot.7z"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\\" x C:\\Data\\Install\\$filename -oC:\\data\\install\\test -aoa >NUL}
Remove-PSSession $session
Exit-PSSession
'''
```

If I change the Invoke-Command to the following, the Program Files directory seems to be resolved correctly, but then the variable $filename is not resolved anymore.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {cmd /c \'"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" x C:\\Data\\Install\\$filename -oC:\\data\\install\\test -aoa >NUL'}
```

> powershell.exe : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException At
>   C:\web\Jenkins\workspace\XXX@tmp\durable-53dbead2\powershellWrapper.ps1:5
>   char:3
>   +   & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Fi ...
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (NotSpecified: (...RemoteException:String) [], RemoteException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
> - PSComputerName        : XXXXX
>
> ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> C:\Data\Install\$filename
>
> System ERROR:
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Hopefully you can assist me in this case! The rest of the commands is working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `7z.exe` path in your first command has an **extraneous trailing `\`**, which causes problems:

```
cmd /c "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\\"  # <- trailing \\ shouldn't be there
```

In your 2nd command, **you're using *single* quotes** around the command passed to `cmd /c` (`'...'`), but the contents of `'...'` strings in PowerShell are **treated as *literals*, which explains why `$fileName` was not expanded** (interpolated);
only double-quoted (`"..."`) strings and, within limits, unquoted command arguments are expanded in PowerShell; e.g., compare the output from `Write-Output '$HOME'` to the output from `Write-Output "$HOME"` / `Write-Output $HOME`.

As iRon mentions, there's **no need to involve `cmd` at all** - PowerShell is perfectly capable of executing command-line programs directly, so this should work:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { & "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" x C:\\Data\\Install\\$using:filename -oC:\\data\\install\\test -aoa >$null }
```

- Due to invoking `7z.exe` directly, now there's no outer quoting needed anymore, and `$fileName` should be expanded.

  - Note, however, that `$fileName` was replaced with **`$using:fileName`**, which is necessary in order for the target session to know about the *local* `$fileName` variable - see [`Get-Help about_Remote_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables).
- Since the `7z.exe` file path is *quoted* (of necessity, due to containing spaces), you must **use `&`, the call operator**, to invoke it.
- Since the `>` redirection is now performed by PowerShell itself, the `cmd`-style `>NUL` output suppression was replaced with its PowerShell analog, **`>$null`**.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it necessarily at all to invoke a `CMD` shell for this.
I guess it would be simpler to directly invoke the `7z.exe` with its parameters.

Nevertheless, you can build you own script block like this:

```
[ScriptBlock]::Create('cmd /c "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" x C:\\Data\\Install\\' + $filename + ' -oC:\\data\\install\\test -aoa >NUL')
```